# Ботинок или ботинков не жаль? Доспех или доспехов не жаль?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Доспех в значении "нательное средство индивидуальной защиты" или доспехи в значении "комплект средств индивидуальной защиты" не является чем-то необчным, однако смущает употребление данного слова в следующем контексте:

Защита доспех(ов) напрямую зависит от умения ими владеть.

В данном случае я никак не могу определить, как было бы правильно - доспех (в множественном значении) или доспехов?
Единственное, что приходит в голову - это старая песня, в которой была такая строчка:

*Smile, m****r f****r, smile! Я иду по дороге и ботинок не жаль!*

В которой *ботинок* использовалось во множественном числе. Можно задать аналогичный вопрос - ботинок или ботинков?

Comment: А что рекомендуют словари, смотрели? ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8 === http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B8&all=x

Comment: А можно убрать мат из Вашей цитаты (оставить только русскую часть или заменить каким-то обозначением пропуска только его)?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Правда это не мат, а зарубежная нецензурная лексика, сохраненная ради точности цитаты. Уже убрал.

Comment: Спасибо, Kodek! А в чём разница между матом и зарубежной нецензурной лексикой, кстати?

Comment: Например, в том, что мат - он русский. А зарубежную нецензурную лексику не все знают и не все могут прочитать =)
К, лично моему, сожалению, не смотря на то, что английский язык является международным, его знают и понимают далеко не все.

Comment: А я для простоты все нецензурные слова во всех языках матом называю. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Не жаль ботинок и доспехов,** именно эти формы указаны в толковом словаре.

Пояснение

Основным окончание существительных м.р. в форме Р.п. мн. числа (после твердой основы) является окончание ОВ, именно оно используется в форме "доспехов".

Нулевое окончание является вариантным  и применяется в отдельных тематических группах, в частности для парных предметов (ботинки - ботинок).

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.morfologija.ru/словоформа/ботинков](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Я бы тоже не стал запрещать слово "ботинков", а подыскал бы ему подходящее употребление: 
в паре **ботинок** каждый из **ботинков** обладает индивидуальностью.

```
Таких ботинков одноногий давным-давно не надевал.
```

или:

```
- Видишь тех двух мужиков? Вот два сапога пара - дымят сигарами.
- Да, только я часы забыл. Пойдем, спросим у этих двух ботинков время.
```

Comment: Всё закономерно: для парных предметов форма "ботинок",  а для индивидуальных - ботинков, тем более в переносном смысле. Но эти варианты должны хорошо различаться, иначе получится просто неграмотная речь.

Answer (score 1):

Такова словарная рекомендация:
 ботинок,***-нок, -нкам;*** ***мн***. (**ед.** ботинок, ***-нка; м.***)
Доспехи, ***-ов; мн***. (***ед.*** доспех, **-а; м.**).